# three small absolutely positioned divs in my homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three small absolutely positioned divs in my homepage. i want only one div to appear at a time, so that the page should start with only the first div and after 3 seconds, the second div and after 3 seconds the third div and this process should continue infinitely. this is the for-loop I've come up with for doing this 10 times. how can i make the same happen infinitely?

```
// this for not making infinite loop
var nb_loop=0;
var max_loop=10; 
var j=0;
for (var i=2; i<=3 ; i++){
  nb_loop++;
  j++;
  console.log("i="+i+", j="+j); // or alert if you want
  if (j>=3)
    j=0;
  if (i>=3)
    i=0;
  if (nb_loop>max_loop)
    break; 
}
```

Comment: why dont you use css or jquery??

Comment: an inifinite loop will break your browser, though here's the infinite `for` `for(;;)`

Comment: no, i need to support older browsers as well. so no css3 animations.

Comment: no, that happens only after 3 seconds, huh, with setInterval()

Answer (score 1):

**JS:**

```
var counter = 1;
function showDiv(){
$('.display').hide();
$('#div'+counter).show();
(counter == 4 ? counter = 1 : counter++)
}

showDiv();
var timer = setInterval(showDiv, 3000);
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div id='container'>
   <div id='div1' class='display' style="background-color: red;"> 
        div1
   </div>

    <div id='div2' class='display' style="background-color: green;"> 
       div2
    </div>

    <div id='div3' class='display' style="background-color: blue;"> 
       div3
    </div>

     <div id='div4' class='display' style="background-color: yellow;"> 
       div4
     </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .display { display: none; }
```

Use Jquery **setInterval** function use for infinite time

Answer (score 0):

use **JQUERY SETTIMEOUT()** function

like this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //hide a div after 3 seconds
   setTimeout(function(){ jQuery("#div").hide(); }, 3000);

 });
```